# Is there any IP to GeoLocation service avaliable which provide any accuracy radius/ accuracy measure?

Tags: geolocation, ip, geocoding, ip-geolocation

I know Maxmind geo_IP location provide an accuracy_radius parameter. Is there any other IP-Geolocation service that provide same accuracy radius?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Apart from MaxMind, IP2Location also provides accuracy radius. This is [MaxMind](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-city-accuracy-comparison) accuracy radius page and here is the similar one from [IP2Location](https://www.ip2location.com/data-accuracy).

This [Quora Answer](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-the-most-accurate-IP-geolocation-service) summarizes the accuracy of various services very well.